# Where is the Cygwin config.log file located

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin, libevent

I have installed cygwin recently and have installed all the required packages. I was trying to install libevent-2.1.8-stable. When I did ./configure it shows C compiler cannot create executables. See config.log for more details. But where can I find the config.log file? I have searched the cygwin installation directory but found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the config.log is produced by configure and it is in the directory where you run `./configure`

`C compiler cannot create executables` could mean:
you have missed to install something or likely an antivirus is interfering with the compiler.